# Custom Validation between 2 properties float range Asp .Net Core

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-2.2

I have these 2 properties in a model

```
public class Geometria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Componente { get; set; }

    [Range(0, float.MaxValue)]   
    public float ToleranciaInferior { get; set; }

    [Range(0,float.MaxValue)]
    public float ToleranciaSuperior { get; set; }     
}
```

The property ToleranciaSuperior cannot be the same or equal as ToleranciaInferior.

How can i achieve this with annotations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900485/custom-validation-attributes-comparing-two-properties-in-the-same-model

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't sure what to search for about my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be more convenient to put custom validation logic in the viewmodel itself, unless you find yourself doing this on more than one viewmodel.

```
public class Geometria : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Componente { get; set; }

    [Range(0, float.MaxValue)]   
    public float ToleranciaInferior { get; set; }

    [Range(0,float.MaxValue)]
    public float ToleranciaSuperior { get; set; }     

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ToleranciaInferior == ToleranciaSuperior) 
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                "Your error message", 
                new string[] { 
                    nameof(ToleranciaInferior), nameof(ToleranciaSuperior) 
                });
        }
    }
}
```