# ValidationAttribute based on the value of another property

Tags: c#, .net, modelstate, validationattribute

I know how to create a ValidationAttribute. But how can I check something based on the value of another property?

For example this model :

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get;set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [CustomValidator(ErrorMessage =  "If BE city cannot be null...")]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Country is mandatory but if the Country == "BE" the property City cannot be null.

Is this possible with ValidationAttribute?

Comment: Yes this is possible.  [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900485/custom-validation-attributes-comparing-two-properties-in-the-same-model)

Comment: Possible, yes, but tricky: http://www.alessandrocolla.com/validate-a-value-based-on-the-value-of-another-property/ this is also interresting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390902/requiredif-conditional-validation-attribute