# Custom Conditional Validation For Required fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, validation

How can I some custom validation logic to `Required` attribute? I need to let empty `Name` when `IsMain` is set to `"off"`.

```
[BindProperty]
[RequiredCustom(IsMain == "off")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public string IsMain { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can do as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901736/8404545)

Comment: Is your problem solved ? Do you want client validation or sever validation or both ?

Answer (score 0):

> let empty Name when IsMain is set to "off"

When Name is empty, the required error we will get(asp.net core 6+), so we can add `?` to avoid the the required error, then do client validation to let empty Name when IsMain is set to "off".

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    [RequiredCustom]        
    public string ? Name { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string IsMain { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        { }
        
    }
}
```

RequiredCustomAttribute:

```
public class RequiredCustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-anothertest", GetErrorMessage());
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage() =>
        "Name is required";


    private static bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }

        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<form asp-action="Index">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="IsMain" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="IsMain" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="IsMain" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div id="errormess" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

    <script>
        $.validator.addMethod("anothertest",
            function (value, element, parameters) {
                var val1 = $("#IsMain").val();
                if ((value == "") && (val1 != "off") ) {
                    return false
                }
                else {
                    return true
                }
            });

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("anothertest");
    </script>
```

result:
[image]